# Слово «Фатаграфiя»

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы, заимствования

Смотрю сериал «Блиндаж», вдруг заметил эту надпись ([см.](https://pp.vk.me/c622628/v622628132/4029c/sm7zqTbKfqo.jpg) скриншот). Почему написано так? Время действий — сороковые года.

Comment: Может быть, дореволюционный фотограф специализировался на съёмке свадеб, а знак просто остался на здании. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А действие сериала не в Белоруссии происходит? По белорусски "фотография" пишется именно так. Дореволюционное написание через "о".

Comment: Ах, я тоже попробовал исследовать этот вопрос, но опоздал ответить. :( Да, насколько я понял, съёмки как раз в Белоруссии, по крайней мере частично. "Июль 1941 года. Отступающая воинская часть готовится дать немцам бой. Кругом полное столпотворение. Население белорусского села Любаши частью уходит с войсками, частью бежит в лес. Тут же и наступающие немцы. Идет бой, сплошной грохот и разрывы снарядов… И вдруг все стихло. Фронт отодвинулся дальше на восток".